# How can I get a view in Sencha Touch 2 from within a controller by calling a function automatically generated by the ref config?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have defined a controller in Sencha, that includes a refs attribute referencing my view, yet whenever I call the automatically generated "get" function to get the view, based on the refs attribute, it returns undefined. Here is my example:

I have the following controller in app/controller/Locals.js:

```
Ext.define('MobileUnion.controller.Locals', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    // Base class methods.
    launch: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    init: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    config: {
        refs: {
        localsEditorView: 'localseditorview',
    },
    control: {
        localsEditorView: {}
    }
    },
    slideUpTransition: { type: 'cover', direction: 'up' },
    onEditLocalsCommand: function() {
        this.activateLocalsEditor();
    },
    activateLocalsEditor: function() {
        var localsEditorView = this.getLocalsEditorView();
        console.log(localsEditorView);  // Returns "undefined" to console.
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(localsEditorView, this.slideUpTransition);
    }
});
```

I have the following view in app/views/LocalsEditor.js:

```
Ext.define('MobileUnion.view.LocalsEditor', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.localseditorview',

    config: {
        html: 'This is the new view which should show up on top!'
    },
});
```

So, in the above example, if I call `this.getLocalsEditorView()` from within my controller, I get "undefined" even though I set a refs attribute as `localsEditorView: 'localseditorview'` and I defined MobileUnion.view.LocalsEditor to include an alias of `widget.localseditorview`. I feel like I should get the view when I do this.

By the way, I did define the view in the `views` attribute of my app.js, so that's not it.

Further information: there's no actual error being returned in my webkit console. Just the call to `console.log()` noted above in my controller returns undefined, rather than the view object.

Question: What do I have to do to make this function return the view, and not undefined? Any help would be appreciated. I've looked to make sure it's not just a typo; it does not seem to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "refs" is to create references to existing components. So far all you've done is declare a class, from what you've posted you've never instanced it anywhere.

You might want to read the docs about autoCreate here:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs